# finding a point on an ellipse circumference which is inside a rectangle having center point, height and width?

Tags: .net, math, geometry, ellipse

I have a rectangle in .NET in which I draw an ellipse.

I know the width, height and center point of that rectangle.

Of course the center point of the rectangle is also the center point of the ellipse.

I know how to calculate a point on a circle, however I have no clue about an ellipse.

I have those parameters and an angle, i need the point on the ellipse, can someone post the formula?

I saw somewhere you need to calculate 2 points in which 2 radii will go, the sum of the radii will be fixed and they will change in size accordingly.

I don't know how to do that, I only have the rectangle height, width and center point and of course the angle I wish to find the point at.

thanks for any help
Shlomi

Comment: This belongs on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Ganesh R : not all questions about math belong on mathoverflow. In fact, *very few* of the questions people on SO *say* belong on mathoverflow actually do belong on mathoverflow. Have a read of its FAQ.

Comment: @Shlomi : are the sides of the rectangle parallel to the axes?

Comment: Yes,

This is quite a simple ellipse using the implemented Drawing2D DrawEllipse function.

I create a rectangle and then just draw the ellipse.
The rectangle`s origin is set by TopLeft point and the center is always Width/2,Height/2 of the rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean by "angle" in your post?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [canonical form in polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_form_in_canonical_position) for your problem where the width and height of a rectangle is *w* and *h* respectively.

[image]

[image]

where *t* is an angle in radians, *a* is *w/2* and *b* is *h/2*

So to plot your ellipse, all you have to do is vary *t* from *0* to *360* degrees (in radians so that's *0* and *2pi*) and depending on how you space out *t*, you get the points on the ellipse.

Since your rectangle is not centered at the origin, you will have to offset it by the coordinates of the center of the rectangle, say, *(C<sub>x</sub>,C<sub>y</sub>)*

```
const double C_x = 10, C_y = 20, w = 40, h = 50;
for(double t = 0; t <=2*pi; t+=0.01)
{
   double X = C_x+(w/2)*cos(t);
   double Y = C_y+(h/2)*sin(t);
   // Do what you want with X & Y here 
}
```

Comment: What if I just wanna to pass an given X and get the Y related to the elipse? How should I procceed?

Comment: Then you can solve for `t` and plug it into `Y(t)`. E.g. if `a = 1, b= 1` and you have `X = 1`, then `X = a cos(t)` or `1 = 1*cos(t)` which means `t = 0` is a solution. Thus, `Y(t) = 0`.