# Basic maths for animation

Tags: c#, .net, animation, graphics, geometry

Assuming I have a form and paint an oval on it. I then want to take a control (such as a picturebox) and (while keeping the top left corner of the control exactly on the line) I want to move the control pixel by pixel following the drawn oval.

Basically I want to calculate the Top/Left point for each position/pixel in my oval. I know its a basic formula but cant for the life of me remember what its called or how its accomplished.

Anyone care to help?

[image: Example]

Comment: Not your exact question but close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781206/finding-a-point-on-an-ellipse-circumference-which-is-inside-a-rectangle-having-ce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double step=1.0; //  how fast do you want it to move

double halfWidth=100.0; //  width of the ellipse divided by 2
double halfHeight=50.0; //  height of the ellipse divided by 2

for (double angle=0; angle<360; angle+=step)
{
    int x=(int)halfWidth * Math.Cos(angle/180*Math.PI);
    int y=(int)halfHeight * Math.Sin(angle/180*Math.PI);
    pictureBox.TopLeft=new Point(x,y);
}
```

EDIT:

Now, if you are about to ask why isn't it moving if you write it like that - you'll have to add message loop processing to it, in form of:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

which you will place inside the loop.

Comment: @Dve - I was doing it since '83 on ZX Spectrum, it was my first 'program' :)

Comment: Wanna fix your code up and I'll mark it as the answer? Math.Cos(x/180*Math.PI); and Math.Sin(y/180*Math.PI); is wrong (I think you meant width and height????) along with a double declaration of x.

Comment: @Maxim - here it is - it's the angle that should go into the loop, not x and y - my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Ellipse canonical form:

```
x-x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
```

where `a` = Xradius and `b` = Yradius. So, for example, if you want the top-left point of a rectangle on the bottom side of an ellipse:

```
y = Sqrt((1-x^2/a^2)*b^2)
```

upd: to move an ellipse to specified point `XC,YC`, replace each x with `(x-XC)` and `(y-YC)`. so if you're (in C#) drawing an ellipse in a rectangle, so `XC = rect.X + a` `YC = rect.Y + b` and the final equation is `y = Sqrt((1 - Pow(x - rect.X - rect.Width / 2, 2) * Pow(rect.Height / 2, 2)) + rect.Y + rect.Height / 2`... seems to be correct)